# Laravel / Carbon - Return diffForHumans() in the shorter format like instagram

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-carbon

Have my API returning diffForHumans() on my created at date:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value)->diffForHumans();
}
```

This creates e.g.

```
1 day ago
6 days ago
3 weeks ago
1 month ago
```

But What I wish for is to have the same as Instagram where it returns simply:

```
1d
6d
3w
1m
```

Is there a way to do this apart from perhaps splitting the returned value by spaces and taking the first letter of the second word and the number?

EDIT: One of those lovely occasions where typing out a question solves it for you.

This is what I just came up with quick. Seems to work but open to any other solutions.

```
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $diffForHumans = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value)->diffForHumans();
        $data = explode(" ", $diffForHumans);

        $number = $data[0];
        $denominator = substr($data[1], 0, 1);
        return $data[0] . $denominator;
    }
```

Comment: The one problem I see with your solution is minutes and months both starting with m.  In most circumstances, I would assume m means minutes, not month.

Answer (score 1):

Carbon doesn't have this built in, but it should be simple enough to manipulate the output like this:

```
str_replace([' days', ' day'], 'd', $diffForHumans);
```

Answer (score 0):

Carbon has this built in:

`$object->diffForHumans(null, null, true);`

`public function diffForHumans($other = null, $syntax = null, $short = false, $parts = 1, $options = null);`